# How can I assign multiple values which are parameter to a function to single variable given the condition that the function is in another file in Py

Tags: python, decimal, quantize

I have a file `num.py` in which I have defined a variable as

```
import decimal

fivedecimal = Decimal(10) ** -5
```

This particular variable is being used in other python files as:

```
import decimal

from num import fivedecimal

b= decimal.Decimal(100.05).quantize(fivedecimal)
```

Now the problem I am facing is that I have to add a parameter for `rounding=ROUND_CEILING` but I have to do that in the first file only as the variable `fivedecimal` is being used in multiple files in different contexts for quantizing values to five decimal places, but I want to make a change in only the first file so that I don't have to make changes in the multiple files where I am importing `fivedecimal`.

Basically my question is if there is a way in which I can specify the two parameters as a variable in the first file (`num.py`) that is `fivedecimal = (Decimal(10)** -5, rounding=ROUND_CEILING)` and then automatically wherever I am using the `fivedecimal` variable the decimals are being rounded off as this will save me a lot of time as there are more than 250 places where I am using the `fivedecimal` variable and if this is not possible then I will have to make the changes in all the 250 places by adding an extra parameter `rounding=ROUND_CEILING` i.e. `quantize(fivedecimal, rounding=ROUND_CEILING)`.

Comment: The proper fix would probably be to subclass `decimal` to implement this additional behavior. Are you familiar with classes and inheritance?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little....are you saying that I have to create a subclass of decimal class and implement this behavior, if yes then how should I be doing it, please help.

Comment: Something like that; but it also depends on how exactly the variable is being used. If you always call `quantize` on it, wrapping this method could work instead, or as well.